# Hyper-V with "Hypervisor is not running" and I did the BCDEDIT already

Tags: hyper-v

I followed all the different guides on superuser, but no luck.

I did the bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype auto as Administrator and rebooted.

I run Windows 10 and I do not run VMWare or others.

The only security software I run is Windows Defender, and on the Device Security page it says:

Standard hardware security not supported. (This means that your device does not meet at least one of the requirements of standard hardware security.)

I wonder if that is the reason?  Is my motherboard, BIOS or CPUs too old?

[image]

Comment: Do you have Core Isolation enabled?  Do you have any security software that uses Hardware Virtualization installed?  Edit your question instead of submitting a comment.

Comment: You have provided zero details about your hardware.  So is Core Isolation enabled or disabled, or is it disabled due to your hardware or supporting hardware virtualization?